# Mergesort in python - too slow?

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.7, sorting, mergesort

I'm trying to learn merge sort but I'm not sure I got this quite right. It works and I've tried optimizing this e.g. with deques for leftpop but I still get times that are roughly 4 times slower than the builtin sorted() function. Is this supposed to happen? Or am I missing some obvious bottlenecks?

```
import random
from time import time
from collections import deque

unsorted = [random.randint(0, 1000) for r in xrange(101101)]


def merge_sort(unsorted_list):
    length = len(unsorted_list)
    if length <= 1:
        return unsorted_list

    left = unsorted_list[:length / 2]
    right = unsorted_list[length / 2:]

    left_sorted = deque(merge_sort(left))
    right_sorted = deque(merge_sort(right))

    new = []
    while left_sorted and right_sorted:
        if left_sorted[0] < right_sorted[0]:
            new.append(left_sorted.popleft())
            if not left_sorted:
                new += right_sorted
        else:
            new.append(right_sorted.popleft())
            if not right_sorted:
                new += left_sorted
    return new


s = time()
print merge_sort(unsorted)
e = time()
print e - s

s = time()
print sorted(unsorted)
e = time()
print e - s
```

Edit: A somewhat optimized version below:

```
def merge_sort(unsorted_list):
    length = len(unsorted_list)
    if length <= 1:
        return unsorted_list

    left = unsorted_list[:length / 2]
    right = unsorted_list[length / 2:]

    left_sorted = deque(merge_sort(left))
    right_sorted = deque(merge_sort(right))

    new = []

    new_append = new.append
    left_pop = left_sorted.popleft
    right_pop = right_sorted.popleft

    while left_sorted and right_sorted:
        if left_sorted[0] < right_sorted[0]:
            new_append(left_pop())
        else:
            new_append(right_pop())

    if not left_sorted:
        new += right_sorted
    if not right_sorted:
        new += left_sorted

    return new
```

Comment: 4 times slower than an highly optimized, builtin C function isn't slow.

Comment: Damn you're right. I totally forgot for a moment that CPython ISN'T written in Python. Well then, at least here's some code for anyone that google mergesort python.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this should go into CodeReview.Stackexchange.com

Comment: When I run the examples your code isn't 4 times slower. It's more like 17x slower (optimized-`merge_sort`-time: 1.72 s, `sorted`-time: 94 ms).

Comment: Also to keep your merge-sort stable shouldn't you check `if right_sorted[0] < left_sorted[0]`?

Answer (score 1):

There are some name lookups you could cache. I see you doing `.append` and `.popleft` a lot. Try storing those in local variables:

```
new_append = new.append
left_pop = left_sorted.popleft
right_pop = right_sorted.popleft

 ...

new_append(left_pop())

...

new_append(right_pop())
```

That should knock out some opcodes.

Also, your `if not left_sorted:` and right_sorted logic could be moved outside the loop.

You might not need to use a dequeue if you use index variables - left[li] and right[ri] instead of left[0] and right[0] all the time. Destroying the sublists one at a time isn't useful. (I don't know if this will speed things up, however. The dequeue might cache the start-index and do it this way.)

And the if statements at the end should be positive, not negative. It's possible (likely, even) to run out of both at the same time.

Comment: Hey, that actually helped. The if statements were an obvious mistake on my part. The name lookups I wouldn't think of, but they are nice. I'm now down to about 2,5 times slower than sorted() which is cool. Thanks.

Comment: Update the question.

Comment: It's not really possible to run out of both at the same time since I'm doing it one by one so I will check the condition after every digit is sorted and if any of the lists is empty I'll just put the rest at the end.
And AFAIK pop(0) on a list is significantly slower than leftpop() on deque.

Comment: You're right. My bad. On the other hand, `li += 1` might be faster than a call to `popleft` - it's worth a try.

Answer (score 1):

It is slow because you copy the two half (unsorted) lists instead of using indexes.

```
def merge(liste):
    def order(start1,middle,stop2):
        stop1=start2=middle
        index1=start1
        index2=start2
        merge_list=[]
        while index1<stop1 and index2<stop2:
            if liste[index1]<liste[index2]:
                merge_list.append(liste[index1])
                index1+=1
            else:
                merge_list.append(liste[index2])
                index2+=1
        if index1<stop1:
            merge_list.extend(liste[index1:stop1])
        if index2<stop2:
            merge_list.extend(liste[index2:stop2])
        liste[start1:stop2] = merge_list

    def sort(start,stop):
        middle=(start+stop)//2
        if start+1<stop:
            sort(start,middle)
            sort(middle,stop)
            order(start,middle,stop)

    sort(0,len(liste))
    return liste
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to optimize the code as shown below, but it's only a bit faster.

I did a one time "allocation" for a working list, then avoided copy back by using two merge sort functions, one that sorts into original list, the other that sorts into working list.

On my system, Intel 3770K 3.5ghz, Windows 7 64 bit, Python 2.7, when sorting 100,000 integers, the "optimized" version above takes about 0.468 seconds, while the version below takes about 0.320 seconds. The overhead for interpreting code seems to be the bottle neck. The same algorithm as shown below compiled in C++ takes about .0067 seconds, about 47 times as fast.

```
import random
from time import time

def sort(a):
    b = a                               # "allocate" b
    msa2a(a, b, 0, len(a))              # merge sort a to a

def msa2a(a, b, low, end):              # merge sort a to a
    if((end - low) < 2):                # if < 2 elements
        return                          #   return
    mid = (low+end)//2                  # set mid point
    msa2b(a, b, low, mid)               # merge sort left  half to b
    msa2b(a, b, mid, end)               # merge sort right half to b
    mrg(b, a, low, mid, end)            # merge halves   from b to a

def msa2b(a, b, low, end):              # merge sort a to b
    if((end - low) < 2):                # if < 2 elements
        b[low] = a[low]                 #   copy 1 element from a to b
        return                          #   return
    mid = (low+end)//2                  # set mid point
    msa2a(a, b, low, mid)               # merge sort left  half to a
    msa2a(a, b, mid, end)               # merge sort right half to a
    mrg(a, b, low, mid, end)            # merge halves   from a to b

def mrg(a, b, ll, rr, ee):              # merge a pair of runs from a to b
    o = ll                              # o = b[]        index
    l = ll                              # l = a[] left   index
    r = rr                              # r = a[] right  index
    while True:
        if(a[l] <= a[r]):               # if a[l] <= a[r]
            b[o] = a[l]                 #   copy a[l]
            o += 1
            l += 1
            if(l < rr):                 #   if not end of left run
                continue                #     continue (back to while)
            b[o:ee] = a[r:ee]           #   else copy rest of right run
            return                      #     and return
        else:                           # else a[l] > a[r]
            b[o] = a[r]                 #   copy a[r]
            o += 1
            r += 1
            if(r < ee):                 #   if not end of right run
                continue                #     continue (back to while)
            b[o:ee] = a[l:rr]           #   else copy rest of left run
            return                      #     and return

# test sort
a = [random.randint(0, 1000) for r in xrange(100000)]
s = time()
sort(a)
e = time()
print e - s

# check to see if data was sorted
f = 0
for i in range (1 ,len(a)-1):
    if(a[i-1] > a[i]):
        f = 1
        break
if(f == 0):
    print("sorted")
else:
    print("error")
```